# bitbucket: search for partial package name not working

Tags: bitbucket

I want to search a bit bucket repo for partial package names in a java projects imports. I tried all of the following as search terms but both return no results even though I'm positive the results are there.

Any suggestions? Is search indexing just broken on my BB instance?

- project:PROJ1 repo:my.cool.project "package.name"
- project:PROJ1 repo:my.cool.project package.name
- project:PROJ1 repo:my.cool.project "com.company.package.name"
- project:PROJ1 repo:my.cool.project "import com.company.package.name"